# How to pass double quotes to subprocess without setting shell to true?

Tags: python, shell

I need to use double quotes when passing a command to `subprocess` and can't use `shell=true`. The following is simplified version of the code for clarity:

```
def run_command(cmd):
    if isinstance(cmd, str):
        cmd = cmd.split()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = proc.communicate()
    if proc.returncode != 0:
       raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd, error)

cmd = 'sh -c " sudo ls "'
run_command(cmd)
```

I tried the followings but still fails:

```
cmd = 'sh -c " sudo ls "'  #sudo: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
cmd = 'sh -c "sudo ls"'    #ls": Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
cmd = 'sh -c sudo ls'      #usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
```

Comment: Those "unterminated quoted string" errors sound like something is actually escaping this code?  Are you editing / executing it in some odd manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a string input with `.split()` is going to get in your way here as `split()` will not respect your quotes.

Instead try `Popen(['sh', '-c', 'sudo ls'])`

Note that the double quotes are not present. This is because the entire string `sudo ls` (including space) is placed into one `argv` entry this way.